# Why we haven't boolean datatype in Firebird?

Tags: boolean, firebird

Unless I'm totally wrong, we have no boolean datatype (1 bit) in Firebird, even SQL Server. Why? I think boolean usefull in various situations... And very low space consuption...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firebird 3 introduces the boolean datatype. See the [Firebird 3 release notes, BOOLEAN data type](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-boolean). You can get Firebird 3 from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/

See also the original announcement: http://asfernandes.blogspot.com/2010/12/introducing-boolean-datatype.html

Answer (score 5):

you have to create domain for it

```
CREATE DOMAIN D_BOOLEAN
 AS smallint
 CHECK (VALUE IS NULL OR VALUE IN (0, 1));
```

and then

alter table sometable add somefield d_boolean

works perfectly at our DB :)

Comment: This does not improve on space requirements. It still uses 16 bits.

Comment: @RayGoudie - This answer worked in 2013. Im sure that now there are better ideas ;)

Answer (score -3):

Firebird has booleans, in the form of the `bit` data type.

http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-data-types.html

FTA:

**Converting the bit data type**

The bit data type is used to hold a single boolean value, 0 or 1. MS SQL does not support assigning NULL to this fields. InterBase can emulate this with an INTEGER or a CHAR(1) data type.

The acceptable values can be restricted using domains. For more information on Firebird domains, see the Data Definition documentation.

Comment: I disagree, Firebird does not have a bit data type also, as your post states at first, but clarifies then... what Firebird have is Integer and Chars to emulate the bit or boolean fields.

Comment: I also think that *emulation* does not equal to the native boolean data type.